# Update a database generated option

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF model class Magazine.

I have a property MagazineCode which is a database generated option (trigger) .

```
Property(o => o.MagazineCode).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

When i insert a new magazine everything works fine. I can retrieve my MagazineCode after i `.SaveChanges()` and can send the generated MagazineCode to a 3rd party.

I want to generate the magazine code when i insert and after that to have the possibility to update.

If i try to update now, EF makes fun of me as it must as i flagged the column to be database generated.

Is there a way to keep that column database generated (at insertion) and have the possibility to update (after the insertion) ?

Comment: using sql server? if it was a autogeneration  column with identity(1,1) its not possible to update the column

Comment: using sql server. it isn't an autogenerated column with identity. as i said is a column generated by a trigger only at insert